# Upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 breaks joomla

Tags: joomla

I did the do-release-upgrade on my ubuntu server to go from 16.04 to 18.04. I can't seem to identify what it is that's breaking my deployments. I'm new to the ssl certs. Would doing an upgrade make my certs go outta wack?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your php version. Ubuntu 18.04 comes along with php7.2

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.2
```

May be you also need to install some php software.
To list all of them you have installed:

```
apt list php* --installed
```

If you have only php7.0-mysql fore example but not the php7.2-mysql you schould probably install it too, to get joomla the new php7.2.

I'm quite sure, your cert will still work on Ubuntu 18.04.